# Combine two mysql COUNT(*) results, different columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to combine the counts for the following queries:

```
  SELECT recipient AS otheruser, COUNT(*) 
    FROM privatemessages 
   WHERE sender = '$userid' 
GROUP BY recipient

  SELECT sender AS otheruser, COUNT(*) 
    FROM privatemessages 
   WHERE recipient = '$userid' 
GROUP BY sender
```

If there anyway to combine these two queries, and add the count(*) together for each 'otheruser'

Comment: you can try union not sure if that what you are looking for

Comment: By "combine the counts" I'm thinking you want to add the numbers of the `COUNT` together? Or am I mistaken and you simply want to combine the queries?  If all you are trying to do is add the values of `COUNT` together, then simply add them together after the query call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to use SUM / Condition

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN sender = '$userid' THEN recipient else sender END AS OtherUser,
     SUM(sender = '$userid') AS RCount,
     SUM(recipient = '$userid') AS SCount,
     COUNT(*) total
FROM
     privatemessages 
WHERE
     '$userid' IN (sender , recipient )
GROUP BY
     OtherUser
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01946/3)

**Update**

I cleaned up the SUM and GROUP BY statements thanks to deltab and Michael Buen

Comment: For the GROUP BY, couldn't you just use GROUP BY OtherUser?

Comment: Also, `CASE WHEN sender = '$userid' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` can be reduced to just `sender = '$userid'`, which is 1 when true and 0 when false.

Comment: @ConradFrix Yes @deltab is correct, you can just do `SUM(sender = blah)`, aggregate functions(SUM,COUNT,etc) ignore null results or null expression. a `(case when condition then 1 else 0 end)` doesn't save your queries from nulls; aggregate functions does it already for you. see this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc43/1

Comment: @MichaelBuen what angers me is I knew you and deltab were right and I was just holding on to some FUD. Thanks I've updated my answer and the DEMO

Comment: re "what angers me is I knew you and deltab were right...", I swear, at first I read this "what angers me is i knew you, and deltab were right..." with Oxford comma perspective :D Should be written as "what angers me is I knew both of you and deltab were right..." but it's a mouthful hahah, I digress. Don't be angry at yourself, take it easy on yourself, cheers! ツ And +1

Comment: @MichaelBuen this was bugging me, I finally realized why I do `CASE WHEN... ` its because `SUM(EXPRESSION)` doesn't work in  SQL Server or Oracle which is where I spend more of my time :P.

Comment: Hahah that's a problem, they don't have proper boolean. Even we throw money at the problem(er.. database vendors), they won't budge to add time-saver language constructs or functions. But at least Microsoft added DATE type in Sql Server 2008; and on SQL Server 2012, they added [IIF(condition,1,0)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1c4a/1). But they are not as generous though, I tried [IIF(condition)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1c4a/2) expecting it to return 1 or 0, but alas it doesn't do our bidding ツ

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is just to use 2 queries.
There is absolutely no harm in requesting 2 different sets of data using 2 queries yet not a single reason to do it with one.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them with UNION like this:

```
SELECT otheruser, COUNT(*) FROM
(SELECT recipient AS otheruser
FROM privatemessages 
WHERE sender = '$userid' 
GROUP BY recipient
UNION
SELECT sender AS otheruser
FROM privatemessages 
WHERE recipient = '$userid' 
GROUP BY sender)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT recipient AS r, sender AS s, COUNT(total) // can't use same alias
FROM privatemessages
WHERE sender = '$userid' AND recipient = '$userid'
GROUP BY s;
```

Then in your results function, call the count

```
while ($row = $result) {
  echo $row['COUNT(total)'];
}
```

I believe this query should work as expected.  The only issue with your original was the dual alias and your grouping of two different fields.  This is possible in 2 seperate queries but combined, it can't be done (at least the alias, don't think so with GROUP BY).

Hope this works for you.

**UPDATE**

A *great* alternative to `COUNT` is to simply use `num_rows`... Therefore, the query above would be:

```
SELECT recipient AS r, sender AS s // can't use same alias
FROM privatemessages
WHERE s = '$userid' AND r = '$userid'
GROUP BY s;
```

And then in your results function, call `num_rows` function:

```
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: hmm I think the wheres statement should be an `OR` not an `AND`

Comment: @ConradFrix The OP is originally calling two separate queries, therefore it should be an `AND` since they are absolute individually, which they are when presented in two separate queries.

Comment: @ConradFrix But you are correct, it would make more sense as an `OR` but I used the `AND` because of the reason stated above.

Comment: I don't want to belabor the point, but I don't think a given User would be both the sender and the recipient on a message, which means it would probably return zero rows,

Comment: @ConradFrix I agree, and not trying to argue but perhaps this query is simply to return how many total messages the given `$userid` has _both_ written _and_ received?  That was the assumption I made anyway.